# Azure Web App vs Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, mobile

I have created an Azure Web App today and it has a Mobile section in the Settings which contains Push notification, Mobile Authentication, etc. You can even download the source code for a mobile client app. I know that this used to be part of Mobile App (Mobile Service). I have created an Azure Mobile App to compare with Web App and they look the same in terms of Settings and Tools. Even the Icon is the same.

My question is what is what is the difference between Azure Web App and Azure Mobile App?

Answer (score 26):

Like you, I couldn't get my head around the difference between the different types of App Service apps (Web Apps / Mobile Apps / API Apps). Judging by the fact that no one has really answered your question, it looks like we weren't the only ones.

It made no sense to me that Web Apps, Mobile Apps and API apps were distinct things: surely the whole point is that you should be able to expose an API that serves your web site, your mobile apps, any other kind of client, making use of whichever features you need for your use case?

And, lo and behold, buried [deep in the Azure docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-service-api-apps-why-best-platform/):

> The only difference between the three app types (API, web, mobile) is the name and icon used for them in the Azure portal.

Yep: **they're exactly the same.**

Comment: Unfortunately this information doesn't appear to be in the docs anymore..

Answer (score 6):

In old days of Azure, they had 2 offerings - Azure Websites and Azure Mobile services. Some time ago, both of them got rolled into something called [`Azure App Service`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/) which also included two more kinds of apps - [`API Apps`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/api/) and [`Logic Apps`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/logic/).

To answer your question specifically, [`Azure Web App`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/web/) is new name for Azure Websites that you can use to build websites in multiple languages where as [`Azure Mobile App`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/mobile/) is the new name for Azure Mobile Service that provides backend infrastructure for mobile applications (or in other words, Azure Mobile App is Mobile Backend-as-a-Service [MBaaS] offering from Azure).

Comment: If you check both of them in Azure portal you see that Web App has the same settings as Mobile App. What's the purpose of it? If you go to the Settings > Mobile you'll see that you can download the Server C# sample which is based on Mobile API. I'm still puzzled. Does it make sense to host an app and an MBaaS on the same instance. I'm talking about the same project instance not in the same App Service Plan.

Answer (score 5):

Mobile Service is the "classic" version and is only available in the classic portal. Mobile Apps is part of App Service is only available in the preview portal.

App Service includes Web Apps, Mobile Apps, API Apps and Logic Apps is deployed as one unit.  Using the classic way, you would have to create and pay let's say for a Web App and a Mobile Service so you can save money using the App Service.  You also get a larger selection of VMs.

Not all Mobile Services features have been migrated yet to Mobile Apps.  If you use a Node.js backend, there's no nice UI built-in in the new portal to manage your JS code.

Note that Microsoft has not announced that it will deprecate Mobile Services.

Comment: All of this is not new to me - I migrated Mobile Services to from old portal to the new one - into the Mobile App. But that doesn't answer my question. What is the difference between Web App and Mobile App from App Services? I understand the difference theoretically but practically the portal doesn't differentiate them. If I need to deploy a web site I will create a Web App - that's clear. But why the Web App has Notifications, mobile clients code source example, etc.

Comment: "but practically the portal doesn't differentiate them"  You just answered your question.  4 services merged in 1 called App Service.

Answer (score 3):

I have found some subtle, but key, differences. Assuming a C# backend, the **Mobile** App Service controllers will inherit from **TableController** - which provides out-of-the-box CRUD operations on a table, compared to the Web Api 2 style ApiController (which you can still use in a Mobile App Service). Any less confused now?

Comment: A little confused.  "compared to the Web Api 2 style ApiController (which you can still use in a Mobile App Service)" so there's MobileController vs WebController?

Comment: A regular ASP.NET Web API 2 project will use a controller of type ApiController (which works in an Azure Mobile App project), however, the Mobile app service starter project uses controllers of type TableController. They appear to be very similar in syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply.  They all are really the same thing.  If you look in Azure Resource Explorer (available in the application menu of your app or resources.azure.com)  you will see the indication of how we display a different icon for it -  "kind": "mobileapp", for Mobile Apps for example.  We leverage the different kinds to provide different quick-starts.  You can certainly create an Azure Web App and load Azure Web App code to it to get the Mobile Functionality.

Comment: I know this discussion is pretty old but as of now(2018) it would seem that Microsoft has abandoned Azure App Mobile App project ? https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/227
Can anyone confirm? Does this mean we should use "regular" web api 2 for mobile backend projects now?