# "Try This Out" missing from new azure mobile app template

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on my first C# Azure mobile app.  I started with the template "azure mobile service" then found a post on here referring to "Azure Mobile App" being the newest template to use. [StackOverFlow Azure Mobile App vs Azure Mobile Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822835/azure-web-app-vs-azure-mobile-app) I wasn't far along so I created a new project based on "Azure Mobile App" and linked to my DB in Azure.  I then ran the base template which should show me the "ToDoItem" which was installed as part of the template and the link to "Try This Out" which was missing from the web page on start.  I'm not getting any errors or warnings.  Anyone know why this is missing from the Azure Mobile Apps template and / or how to get it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the Swagger UI.  YOu can find instructions on the [Server SDK Wiki](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Adding-Swagger-Metadata-and-Help-UI-to-a-Mobile-App)

Comment: Not quite the same as the "Azure Mobile Service" template, but it will do what I need it to do! thanks!